# Is it possible to preload an HTML page before displaying it?

Tags: jquery, preload

I'm not referring to preloading images, I want to preload an HTML page using JQuery.

Comment: Yes, but it would help to know why you're doing it and what effect you want to achieve otherwise the answer you get probably won't be as helpful as it might.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ajax the content in then use as you wish:

```
var myPrefetchedPage;
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    myPrefetchedPage = html;
  }
})
```

myPrefetchedPage is now the full content - which can be injected into the current page (completely replacing the page if required.

If you are just trying to leverage caching as much as possible a hidden iFrame may work better.  You can then use jQuery to cycle the iframe src to fetch multiple pages.

Comment: Thanks! That I guess is what I needed, I'd only need to cache the js associated with the page, not the html page itself.

Answer (score 4):

You could put everything in a div that is not visible, and once the document is ready, make the div visible - although this really isn't "pre-loading" - it is just not displaying anything until everything is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Why yes it is! You could do something like having an iframe for your content, fetching the content separately, and then filling the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Set a class on the body to hide it, then remove it using Javascript at the onload event.

(But why you would want to do this is another question.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load the page via [jQuery.get](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) and then do what you want to with it (in string form) before [displaying](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument) it.  If you insert it into a hidden container, you can manipulate it with the DOM first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

The browser will download assets for and render an entire page in the background. 
When user click that "yourpage" link, the page will display almost instantly.